# Google Cloud SQL root@localhost access denied, unless I reset the password to "" every day

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-sql

I have an App Engine App that uses a Cloud SQL database for storing some data.  I have a cron job that runs a bunch of data gathering code at 1am, and it's failing with the error:

OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

If I go to the Google Developers Console and set the password for root@localhost to "" (ie open the change password dialog, hit OK without entering anything in the password field), the job that the cron job points to finishes without a hitch.  SQL access will then work for the rest of the day.

But the next cron job the following day will fail with the same error.

It seems like the root@localhost password is being reset to something at some point during the night.  Anybody have any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any documentation about `root` user password resets. My guess is that Google has a cron job of their own that forces password resets for `root` users with blank passwords as it is a **major security vulnerability** given the public IP addresses for each Cloud SQL instance.

This ['Creating Users'](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/create-user) article however, does strongly advise against using the `root` account at all.

Without knowing why you need to use a `root` account with a blank password, I would recommend creating a user explicitly for cron jobs with an adequate password. This secures your Cloud SQL instance and makes queries run by cron jobs far easier to monitor.

Comment: You may be right about Google resetting passwords for root if there is no password.  I set the password for root to something and the cron job had no trouble with access over the weekend.  So thanks!  I left the cron job using root because when I was messing around with users and passwords on the developer console I came across a message that says that Google App Engine always connects to Cloud SQL as root@localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SQL never does this. Could you check your cron job to see if it actually deletes the user?